# Quick extraction of structs name from a mat file

Tags: performance, matlab

For a mat file of a 3.5 GB, containing ~300 structs who, whos and Load take the same time, ~30 seconds.

```
>> tic; names2 = whos('-file', 'C:\Users\gideonk\Desktop\X\data.mat'); toc
Elapsed time is 32.931407 seconds.
>> tic; names = who('-file', 'C:\Users\gideonk\Desktop\X\data.mat'); toc
Elapsed time is 32.402112 seconds.
```

If I mark the file in the current folder API, I can see the names of the structs **immediately**. How I can access the name of the structs with the same speed but programmatically, rather than via the API?

[image]

Comment: `who` is takig less time than `load` in your test; so what do you mean by "Should not who take less time then load?" What do you mean by "mark the file"?

Comment: @SardarUsama it takes less but not significantly. mark -> click on it

Comment: You see the names of the structs, not the data. Its a header, metadata that you see. 3.5 Gb in 30s is what a normal computer can do. Buy an SSD, otherwise this is normal. And yes, its likely that 3.5GB of just an array of doubles will take less, as its not structured.

Comment: @AnderBiguri what I need is the names of the struct, which is what I get from "who". How come I see it faster via the interface?

Comment: I bet `who` is implemented in terms of `whos`, and that is why they take the same amount of time to run. Otherwise `who` should take much less time. This is something you should submit as a bug to MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, how I submit a bug to matlab? Do you think that they are not aware of it? Do you think they care and will fix it?

Comment: They do care, but they might take a long time to fix it because they’ve got lots of stuff to fix. They do continuously fix bugs though. You can see known bugs here: https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports — report a bug here: https://servicerequest.mathworks.com/mysr/cp_case_new1?bug=true&cc=us